# Interleaving std::map insertion and iteration

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, iteration, stdvector

If I iterate `std::map` like this:

```
typedef std::map<connection, connectionData> clist;
clist m_connections;

for (const auto itt : m_connections)
{
       connectionData outerPlayerData = itt .second;
// Do stuff 
}
```

and somewhere in the code the `m_connections` getting filled constantly, does it mean the iterating loop will run forever? Is it growing
or it will run the size of the `m_connections` in this point of time and the relevant size which was in that point of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will iterate forever if you keep on adding constantly at position greater than the current iteration position. The elements keep on adding and the loop iteration considers the current status of map.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/0yuWmt)

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    map<int, int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(10, 11));
    int i = 0;
    for(auto it : m){
        cout << it.second << endl;
        if(i++ == 0){ 
            m.insert(make_pair(15, 12));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives output as:

```
11
12
```

NOT

```
11
```

Comment: Now add pair (1, 12) instead. You are in for a big surprise. Also if it was really concurrent, you could hit UB when you are trying to advance iterator to node which is currently being changed.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot. Yes, you are right. The iterator can't look back since it has already moved ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at the iterator invalidation rules for `std::map`, at least the code does not exhibit UB.

Which just leaves two possibilities for anything inserted: It gets inserted earlier or later than your current iteration-position into the container.

If you reliably insert at least one new element per iteration after the current iteration-point, you'll get an infinite loop, otherwise you won't.

So, how do the new elements compare?

The relevant standard-quote:

> 9 The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not aﬀect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.
>   10 The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is deﬁned by the comparison that was used to construct them. For any two dereferenceable iterators `i` and `j` such that distance from `i` to `j` is positive, `value_comp(*j, *i) == false`
>   11 For associative containers with unique keys the stronger condition holds, `value_comp(*i, *j) != false`.

Answer (score 0):

That's dangerous in my opinion. The program may crash. I think you are using multithreading. One is to iterating the map while the other is adding to the map.
Adding to the map may change the underlying structure in the map. That will be a race condition while one thread is modifying and the other is reading the same structure.

@Saurav Sahu In your case, depending on the the value you add, the new value may be added before or after the current iterator. For example, if you insert with key 9 (<10) in the for loop, it still outputs 11.